# Undo a command in emacs and not particularly something that changes the text

Tags: emacs, undo

Can I `undo` the effects of a previous command in `emacs`? For example, suppose I have four buffers open and I press `C-x 1` which deletes other windows and maximizes the active buffer to the whole of the screen. Now, is there a command which when executed brings back the four buffers?

Answer (score 1):

Regular `undo` just undoes changes to text.
To undo changes to window configuration, use:

```
(winner-mode)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") 'winner-undo)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<f7>") 'winner-redo)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now, is there a command which when executed brings back the four
>   buffers?

You can use `winner-mode` to do that. Add the following to your init file

```
(winner-mode)
```

It provides two command for *navigating* through old window configurations, `winner-undo` and `winner-redo` by default they are bound to <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd><kbd>right</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd><kbd>left</kbd> respectively.

> Can I undo the effects of a previous command in emacs?

I am not sure there is anything that will be work for *any* command.

Comment: okay. This will work for this special case. But, is there, in general a command that will bring back the state prior to the last command?

Comment: Hi Sagar, can you define what all constitute a `state` for you? I am asking because depending on your definition of `state` there may or may not be an answer.

Comment: I used state in a more theoretical term. An emacs session can be identified by a state such that if two emacs sessions are in the same state, then one cannot tell the difference between them (visually, or by other means). A command leads to transition between states (and possibly a state change). I want to revert back to the state which existed prior to the executed commands. I will give you one more example. Suppose I change a theme by `M-x select-theme` command, undoing it will bring back the previous theme. Some commands may lead to irreversible state changes, which is okay.

Comment: I that case I guess I do not have an answer sorry :)

Comment: BTW I use the package `workgroups2` which is particularly good at handling buffer and window configuration changes. For example, sometimes I accidently kill a buffer, in such cases it provides a really useful command `wg-undo-wconfig-change` which reopens the file associated with the buffer and also restore the point I was on, in the buffer.Of course you can manually reopen the file but I find having a single keystroke to do it really useful.